# Use of articles with the parties of a contract

Tags: articles, legalese, indefinite-article

Translating a public-offer contract, that is, a contract wherein the first party, usually a company, offers the second party, any interested person, to conclude it under the conditions specified therein, I used "a" writing about the second party because it seems to be "one of many". For example:

> CompanyName LLC complies with laws during providing the services for **a** client.

because it provides the services not for the one specific client but for every of them, and also not "*the services for the client**s***" because it doesn't provide them simultaneously to all the clients since those don't use the services suchwise (all together).

But in several provisions, it becomes necessary to indicate that some action is regarded to be taken by the specific user, for example:

> The contract becomes concluded between **a** client and CompanyName
>   LLC right after completing the registration process by **the** client.

So, writing about the second party, should I better always use "the client" meaning "You", or it's all right with "a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical in American legal documents to define and name the parties and thereafter to refer to them by their names without articles.

Thus:

> CompanyName LLC complies with laws during providing the services for a
>   client.

would most likely say:

**Provider shall comply with all applicable law during the provision of services to Client.**

> The contract becomes concluded between a client and CompanyName LLC
>   right after completing the registration process by the client.

**This agreement between Client and Provider shall come into effect when Client has completed the registration process, assenting to all terms of this agreement.**

Answer (score 1):

*one of many*...let's say *any client* instead.

*the* services is fine because we are talking about the *set* of services provided by the company. Their services are defined. The services they provide to their clients might be listed on their website as well.

But then, when you refer to a client, it's *any* client. And that's the reason, it takes indefinite article. Another safe way to write it is... "the services to **its** client."

When it comes to a contract between two parties, it typically talks about one-to-one approach. The company and the client. It then makes that *any* client into *the* client, the only one who gets into the contract. One of [the legal documents I found is here.](http://vtrnorth.co.uk/pages/terms-and-conditions) It has the definite article for both of them. The client means *a particular client,* it states.

So, to answer your question, use the definite article, when it is one-on-one situation as in contract. Otherwise, if you want to refer to a *general client* (any client), indefinite article is fine.